# Python3 numpy import error PyCapsule_Import could not import module "datetime"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip

I am trying to import numpy with python3 on MacOS mojave. I am getting this error. I don't know if it has something to do with a virtual environment or something like that.

Error:
`PyCapsule_Import could not import module "datetime"`

I have tried reinstalling python3 and reinstalling numpy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my case I had this problem, because my script was called `math.py`, which caused module import problems. Make sure your own python files do not share name with some of common module names. After I renamed my script to something else, I could run script normally.

Comment: What a crazy problem, thanks for this I would have never thought that was the issue.

Comment: How did you debug this? Why does that lead to an importerror for `datetime`?

Comment: Because python imports your local file instead of the library module. I did not debug it, just at one point I tried renaming and it helped.

Comment: @Albert I am pretty sure that there is a file called "datetime.py" in your local, rename it!